# Way map tracker for MapKit or Google Maps

Tags: swift, google-maps, location, mapkit, core-location

Somebody have experience with tracking way what i go with CoreLocation. Like this:

[image]

If somebody have sample please send me link. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `MKCircle`, you can easily make map tracker.

[image]

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - MKMapView delegate

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(userLocation.coordinate, span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated:true)

        let center = userLocation.coordinate
        let circle = MKCircle(center: center, radius: 10)
        mapView.add(circle)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let circleRenderer : MKCircleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay);
        circleRenderer.fillColor = .blue
        circleRenderer.lineWidth = 1.0
        return circleRenderer
    }
}
```